# Element targeting in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that I am using as an expander.  When I click on it uses the toggle function to show/hide the `expander-container` element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expand-icon").click(function () {
        $(".expander-container").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

```
<img class="expand-icon" src="./Content/Icons/toggle-expand-icon.png" alt="some_text" />
<div class="expander-container" >
 ... 
</div>
```

How can I target only the next occurence of the `expander-container` element without targeting all of them on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expand-icon").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".expander-container").toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/XLNM5/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go for go for

```
$(".expand-icon").click(function () {
    $(this).next('.expander-container').toggle(500);
});
```